# Displaying modified parameter value in BIRT

Tags: javascript, birt, maximo

I have two parameters in a very simple report: start date and end date. Those parameters are optional, in the dataset open script I validate whether those two have values or not. If they don't have any value I set end date to the present date and the start date one month backwards.

I am putting directly the parameters in my report as a dynamic text element,and when they have values they are displayed correctly, but when they do not have values I want to show the modified values in the report instead.

Here is the code snippet in the open script I am currently using:

```
if (params["enddate"].value == null)
{
  params["enddate"] = new java.util.Date();
}

var enddate = reportContext.getParameterValue("enddate");

// if parameter startdate is null then set it one month before 

if (params["startdate"].value == null)
{
    var startdate = DateTimeSpan.subDate(enddate, 0, 1, 0);
    params["startdate"] = startdate;
}

startdt_jdbc =    MXReportSqlFormat.getStartDayTimestampFunction(params["startdate"]);
enddt_jdbc =     MXReportSqlFormat.getStartDayTimestampFunction(params["enddate"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the variables startdt_jdbc and enddt_jdbc as globals in the page initialize script. Then these are available troughout the report so you can display them with a normal data element.